# Can't load all iframes

Tags: php, jquery

I can't load all websites inside my iframe for example youtube, facebook and twitter.
I load all my pages from my database, other websites do load normal.

i tried:

js:

```
function showeffect(sUrl,sName)
    {

        $('#effect').hide(1000);
        $('#effect').show(2200);
        $('#website').attr("src", sUrl);

    }
```

php:

```
        <?php 


            $sql = "SELECT naam, url FROM items";
            $database = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=startandhome','root','');
            $results = $database->query($sql); 

            $contentregel = 'contentregelblauw';
            foreach($results as $row) 
            { 

                $itemnaam = $row['naam'];
                $itemUrl = $row['url'];

                echo "<div class=\"" .$contentregel ."\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"showeffect('".$itemUrl ."','".$itemnaam ."'); return false;\">" .$itemnaam ."</a></div>";

                if ($contentregel == 'contentregelgrijs')
                {
                    $contentregel = 'contentregelblauw';
                }
                else
                {
                    $contentregel = 'contentregelgrijs';
                }
            }


        ?>
```

html:

```
<iframe id="website" class="website" src=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because facebook restricts hosting the page in other domain frame. 
usuyally done by attaching the `X-Frame-Options` headers. [X-frame-options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

1. Facebook and twitter sites have x-frame-options, which means they will not allow cross origin calls. they restricted via x-frame-options.